# Invalid ObjectID length MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

When I tried to update the datatype string to `ObjectId` (mongodb 3.2.12 version), I got the error `Invalid ObjectID length` and it converts half of the data as ObjectID. How can I get rid of this error? I have 25k data to update.

```
db.booking.find({user: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) {
    x.user = ObjectId(x.user);
    db.booking.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {user: x.user}});
});
```

Comment: The error suggests that the data is not actually valid for an `ObjectId`, or at least some of it is. If you think it is okay you can always weed out the invalid length entries by adding `$where` to the query `.find({ user: { $exists: true }, $where: 'this.user.length === 24' })` And then deal with anything that does not meet the length requirement of the hex string required as a separate issue. Bottom line is you have some bad data you need to look at separately.

Comment: Can I use this where conditon with this same query. Could you please give me the complete query. Sorry, im not much experience in mongo

Comment: That is the complete query. See it has both your existing condition for the `$exists` as well as the `$where` condition.

Comment: Really thanks a billion. it worked. !!!

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that the data is not actually valid for an **ObjectId**, or at least some of it is. If you think it is okay you can always weed out the invalid length entries by adding `$where` to the query .`find({ user: { $exists: true }, $where: 'this.user.length === 24' })` And then deal with anything that does not meet the length requirement of the hex string required as a separate issue. Bottom line is you have some bad data you need to look at separately